# Does research-oriented position requires good teaching experience

Tags: career

I am wondering if the research-oriented position still requires good teaching experience, for example, is it 1 year teaching experience OK? Or not OK?I understand there is probably no absolute standard. But if you can give me some comments based on your experience, that might be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This varies tremendously depending on the nature of the institution and the position.  You aren't going to get useful answers if you aren't a lot more specific.

Comment: What Andy said. I'll just add that employers know that a new PhD probably won't have a lot of teaching experience and can be expected to adjust accordingly. 

Comment: In the UK, for something like a three year postdoctoral position funded by the EPSRC, we would not require any teaching experience.

Comment: In particular, the answer will depend tremendously on the country and institution. It will depend on whether you're talking about a temporary or permanent position. And it depends on how recruitment works: some places look for very specific specialties, and the more it's the case, the more likely they are to focus on just that one factor. 

Comment: Also, you have to take into account the basic economics of supply and demand in the job market: the question is not so much is teaching experience **required** as is it helpful (and the answer again varies tremendously from place to place). Because you can be sure of one thing: there are a lot of candidates with a lot of teaching experience on the market these days.

Comment: If you're wondering whether you should bother getting teaching experience if you have a chance to do it when it isn't too inconvenient, the answer is **yes**.